# Generic Type to be of class type only in java

Tags: c#, java, generics

C# code:

```
public class XYZ<T> where T : class, new()
```

In .net you can force the generic to be of class type using the above syntex.

My Question is that how we can achieve the same using Java?

Answer (score 1):

In Java there's no constraint which allows you to express that the type must have a no-arg constructor. Contrary to .NET in Java `T` is [erased at runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. And why would you want to? You can't call new on any object `t` declared as `T t` anyway. Can you explain why you would want to do this?

Comment: because in .net you can, and probably he is used to do it that way

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have this special case. Typically you would do the standard thing of using an Abstract Factory.

Constraining the type to have a particular constructor is a static issue, and therefore erasure/reification is not necessary to implement it.